# Added border radius to the background of bar chart in Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am trying to create a bar chart with custom stylings. So needed border radius to the bar. Able to add border radius to the bar but not able to add border radius to the background that were left.
Any idea how can I achieve this. Added my code below. Thank you in advance.

```
                   <BarChart
                        data={timelineDetailsData(metrics.dates.today, metrics.dates.middle)}
                        barGap={14}
                        margin={{
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            left: 0,
                            bottom: 0
                        }}
                        maxBarSize={2000}
                        barSize={100}
                        layout="vertical">
                        <XAxis
                            domain={[0,
                                monthDiff(
                                    new Date(parseInt(metrics.dates.today.split(" ")[1]), getMonthsinNumber[metrics.dates.today.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase()]),
                                    new Date(parseInt(metrics.dates.latest.split(" ")[1]), getMonthsinNumber[metrics.dates.latest.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase()])
                                )]} tick={false} axisLine={false} type="number" tickLine={false} padding={{ left: 0, right: 0 }} />
                        <YAxis type="category" dataKey="currency" axisLine={false} tickLine={false}
                        />
                        <Bar background dataKey="middleDate" fill="#2E76B6" radius={10} barSize={60} >
                            <LabelList dataKey="timelabel" position="insideLeft" style={{ fill: "white" }} />
                        </Bar>
                    </BarChart>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<Bar 
   background={{
       radius: 20
   }}
/>
```